# Android animation for success complete image

Tags: android, xml, animation, android-animation

I have an imageview in which I have 3 images

1. green_circle - which I have to zoom in -> then zoom_out (on specified time)
2. white_tick - which I have to zoom in -> then zoom_out (on specified time)
3. green_sparkle - which zooms in and fades out

Imageview is being setup as following using layer drawables -

```
int[] firstImageArray = new int[]{R.drawable.ic_green_circle, R.drawable.ic_outer_sparkle, R.drawable.ic_white_tick_mark};
Drawable[] layers = new Drawable[firstImageArray.length];
for(int i = 0; i<firstImageArray.length; i++) {
    layers[i] = getResources().getDrawable(firstImageArray[i]);
}
imageView.setImageDrawable(new LayerDrawable(layers));
```

animation files are something similar to this (for zoom-in and zoom-out at specified times):
R.anim.image_circle_zoom :

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="2333"
    >

    <scale
        android:duration="233"
        android:fromXScale="0.0"
        android:fromYScale="0.0"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:toXScale="1.0"
        android:toYScale="1.0" />

    <scale
        android:duration="69"
        android:fromXScale="1.0"
        android:fromYScale="1.0"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:startOffset="1931"
        android:toXScale="1.18"
        android:toYScale="1.18" />

    <scale
        android:duration="165"
        android:fromXScale="1.0"
        android:fromYScale="1.0"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:startOffset="2000"
        android:toXScale="0.0"
        android:toYScale="0.0" />
</set>
```

I have to achieve an animation similar to this [link1](https://lottiefiles.com/1127-success) or [link2](https://lottiefiles.com/1708-success)

I have tried AnimationSet, AnimatorSet and ObjectAnimator but I wasn't able to achieve the desired results. Any help would be appreciated on how it can be achieved?

Answer (score 1):

You add links to Lottie animation files. That files can be included into project directly. Just copy `json` file from site and put it into `LottieAnimationView`. Here is link to [docs](http://airbnb.io/lottie/#/android) and github [repository](https://github.com/airbnb/lottie-android). The easiest way to do such animations is via   lottie files.

Another way is to use `SVG` image, where each part of image should be separate `path`. Then all you need to do is animate that paths via `AnimatedVectorDrawable`. There are a lot of good tutorials on how it can be implemented like [this](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/re-animation-7869722af206) and [this](https://sourcediving.com/android-recipes-the-easy-path-to-animated-icons-878bffcb0920)